# How to apply probability / bayes theory to classification issue?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, classification, conditional-probability

I have a system of Codes which is updated every year, so some codes are deleted and some new codes are added. So here we have 4 versions of this system.

Now, I received a list which contains **some** of these codes but do not know which version of the system this whole list belongs to.

For example:

```
system_2015: 102034,405056, 554489, 443355, 675456, 456444, 478333, 443564, 456723, 675467
List I received:  102034, 675456, 456444, 478333, 443564, 456723
```

Here, I counted a number of codes which match the codes in the 2015,2016...2018 systems and a number of codes which do not exist in a specific version of the system.

Now I want to compute probabilities (or Bayes probability) that list:

- belongs to 2015
- belongs to 2016
- belongs to 2017
- belongs to 2018

number of rows in list = 837

```
               2015  2016   2017  2018  
      Exist:     11   217    625   800  
Don't Exist:    826   620    212    37
```

**Additional info:**

- Number of Codes that are deleted or added new ones by years

  ```
                 2015     2016   2017  2018  
      NEW:    Initial      220     78   300  
  Deleted:    Initial       30     40   113
  ```
- A number of codes in different versions of the system:

  ```
                           2015     2016   2017   2018  
    Number of Codes:       5421     5611   5649   5836
  ```

(Hope I was clear, let me know if something is unclear)

Comment: Probability and classification are two entirely different tasks.  Classification is a forced choice that tries to ignore probabilities as much as possible.

Comment: If list has codes that don't exist in a system version, how could that list belong to that system version?

Comment: Unless you have some information on how the list of codes was constructed, I don't think you can infer much about which year they're from.

Comment: Okay and which method/technique would you offer if not Bayes or probability theory?

Comment: But the priority is to compute probability as described in the question